# GWT textbox disabled in IE8 and IE9

Tags: java, gwt, textbox

I have the problem that different textboxes are disabled in IE8 and IE9, I already tried to set the

```
 textbox.setEnabled(true);
```

but that didn't help, the boxes work fine in safar, firefox and chrome only IE has problems does anyone know why?

Here is the part of the implementation with the textbox:

```
 public class Text extends Composite {
    private TextBox textBox;
    public Text() {
        ...
        textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.setEnabled(true);
        textBox.setValue("test");
        textBox.setFocus(true);
        textBox.setReadOnly(false);
        textBox.setWidth("150px");
        textBox.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
        ...
         )};
         textBox.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {
         ...
         )};

         FlexTable f = new FlexTable();
         f.setWidget(0,0,textBox);

   }
```

I found this [TEXTBOX FOCUS PROBLEM](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5968) but unfortunately thats just a description of the problem and no solution does probably anyone here know a workaround??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "different textboxes". Add your complete code snippet. TextBox works just fine in ie8 and ie9 scenario - http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwBasicText

Comment: "different textboxes" = many textboxes; unfortunately they do not work  in my case... I can set text with textbox.setValue("something") which is displayed in the textbox but I can not click on the textbox as if it is enabled

Comment: Update your question with sample code.

Comment: What happens if you remove your `setFocus` call?

Comment: The issues mentioned indicate the problem only with Tab/Frame/Textbox combination. Is there any chance you can avoid Frame in your use case?

Comment: Most likely, the problem is not with the textboxes, but with your layout. Show your code where you use this textbox. Also, where do you call `initWidget()` in your Text class?

Comment: @Andre It cannot be initWidget() issue as it works in other browser.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer nothing happens if I remove the setFocus

Comment: @SSR unfortunately its a very complicated combination of these three elements therefore its not possible to remove/change the frame or tabs is there really no workaround to this problem??

Comment: The only alternate you can try is drop using GWT Tab and instead emulate a simple container with header labels giving you a GUI feel of tab.

Comment: I tried to use a Button which when clicked on will set the focus on the textbox and that works! So my question would it somehow be possible to trigger an event, after the page is loaded, that sets the focus on the textbox?